# How to deploy my Node server to ec2 using Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, express, jenkins, amazon-ec2

*I have probably been Googling this the wrong way...*

I have a Node express server.

I want to deploy it using Jenkins to ec2.

**What are my options?**

---

1. if I want to upload the code manually, I use ssh... but I want it to
   be  done from Jenkins.
2. Yes the server is on a git repo.
3. I would like a devops flow

Comment: (1 )How are you connecting from your development machine to your ec2 ? ssh keys ?  (2) Are you using some git repository like github, bitbucket or gitlab?  (3)Do you want to create a devops flow or do you just need to be able to deploy a simple application?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you , to do it step by step :

> **Step 1** : Configure correctly a jenkins job ready to build your app in remote ec2 machine.

- Install this plugin in your jenkins platform : [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)
- Using this plugin add **new remote server** under **Publish over SSH** section in **Manage Jenkins >> Configure System** option.

[image]

- Now create some jenkins job. Then, in build section add a step called : **Send files or execute commands over SSH**

[image]

- Just select your configured server and enter your commands in **Exec command** section :

[image]

- For a simple node js express, this code could be enough or just copy-paste your existing code:

https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/38b335f6a5dc8c67a386fd5fb3c6200e

- That is all. Just test with "build" option and verify if your application goes well.
- At this point, this job is functional. The flow could be :

  - push your changes to your git provider
  - login to jenkins and manually execute the created job (this step is replaced with webhook configuration)

**Note:** If and only if this step has no errors, you can start with the following step.

---

> **Step 2** : Implement a simple devops flow by configuring a webhook in your git provider, which automatically triggers the jenkins job (create in **step 1**) when you perform a **git push**.

This guide could be help you with the required configurations :

https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use AWS CodeDeploy jenkins plugin. This apply to any type of code. Node, java etc

See AWS article
[Setting Up the Jenkins Plugin for AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/setting-up-the-jenkins-plugin-for-aws-codedeploy/)

Jenkins Plugin
[Github Link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-plugin)