# Using jenkins to pull git hub code to update Node js app

Tags: node.js, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I hava a NodeJS app running on an ec2 ubuntu instance, and have setup git so I can pull latest code right into the Node app directory. I want to allow a remote Node developer be able to push new code to the Node app remotely, so I installed jenkins on that box, and created a job that just runs a scrip to allow the jenkins user to do a git pull. (I had to add jenkins user to sudoer list so he could change to the git hub user without a password, which I think is probably a security issue). Is there a better way to go about this? It seems like a simple problem, but don't have admin skills.

Answer (score 0):

> I had to add jenkins user to sudoer list so he could change to the git hub user without a password

The Jenkins user shouldn't have to do any `sudo -u otherUser`.

It should use the [JENKINS SSH Credentials Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin) in order to use a dedicate SSH key which would be registered in the GitHub user account: that would give the Jenkins account the capability to access the GitHub private repo (if the repo was public, there would be no need for authentication) and do a git pull. Without having to provide any password.

Comment: I wanted to do it that way, but I could not create an ssh key for jenkins user. It's an account with no password. So I couldn't login as jenkins and create the key.

Comment: @AlperAkture You don't have to login. You only have to register the new SSH key through the SSH Crederntial plugin GUI.

Comment: Credentials plugin seems a bit complicated, I will give it a try as soon as I sort it out. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What about the **Publish Over SSH plugin**

If you can access to your remote ec2 from another machine using your simple ssh key, Jenkins could reuse it and execute any command that is allowed to related ec2 use key.

Also you can configure a simple devops flow to avoid manually steps using webhooks and jenkins.

Here the configuration:

[How to deploy my Node server to ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429874/how-to-deploy-my-node-server-to-ec2)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try it out and let you know how it goes.